# React native upgrade - pod install throws error for config = use_native_modules

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I'm trying to upgrade my react native version to 0.68.2 from 0.66.3.

I have followed [this](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.3&to=0.68.2).

If I try to run `pod install`, it throws:

```
error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations').

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 859: unexpected token at 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

 #  from /Users/me/Documents/app/ios/Podfile:8
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'app' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #    # Flags change depending on the env values.
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "format": "yarn prettier -c '**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx|md)'",
    "format:fix": "yarn prettier --write '**/*.+(js|json|ts|tsx|md)'",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit",
    "commit": "git-cz",
    "generateTypes": "graphql-codegen",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.5",
    "apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "eventemitter3": "^4.0.7",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "i18next": "^21.8.5",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.9",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.8.3",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-notification-sounds": "^0.5.4",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-native": "^5.3.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "victory-native": "^36.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "@graphql-codegen/add": "3.1.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "2.6.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/import-types-preset": "2.1.18",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "2.4.11",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "2.4.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "3.2.14",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^8.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.5",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/apollo-upload-client": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.36",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.7",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "@types/react-router-native": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables": "^0.4.4",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.179.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "lint-staged": ">=12",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.71.0",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.x.x",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.x.x"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

Running on M1, followed instructions how to pod install with m1, same issue.

Just to confirm it is working perfectly with `0.68.2`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In your dev dependencies you have:

```
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^8.0.2",
```

Version 8 is incompatible with React Native 0.68, if you look at the package.json for this version, you can see that the cli version is ^7.

You can either remove this as a direct dependency (probably best), or change your react native cli version to match what is expected in the package.json (7.0.3 as of this writing, but you can always [check the actual file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.68-stable/package.json))

Comment: I have this issue as well. Your solution works well. I wonder how did you find it.